# When to use stored procedures to INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I will be manipulating the database using a program I made, I'm still unsure If I should write a stored procedure to insert new lines or not.

First_Table

```
name_code varchar(10) primary key,
date_ka datetime not null,
amount int not null
```

Second_table

```
code_z int primary key,
date_z datetime not null,
name_code varchar(10) not null,
constraint FK_Key foreign key(name_code) references First_table(name_code)
```

What I think is I should use a stored procedure for the second table to insert so I could check If the primary key actually exists in the first table etc. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Usually you should not do this check - SQL Server will do it for you

Comment: I understand that but a sp is not needed?

Comment: The Stored Procedure depends on several different factors. If you're trying to insert a lot of records in a single shot only within SQL, then the stored procedure would probably work. If you're able to use some sort of managed code (.NET, Java, etc) that can handle errors for you, it isn't as necessary. I'm sure there's something you could even do with regular error handling in SQL, but it's impossible to tell with what you've given in the question.

Comment: @krillgar I just forgot to mention that the primary key in the second table is `default` so It will continue to increase. If I ever put an invalid foreign key, It will increase (code_z) even though It didn't get inserted, right? so isn't a stored procedure a must in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure if it does or not, but why does that matter? Who cares if your IDENTITY column goes from 10 to 12 because something got deleted or an insert failed?

Comment: Asking this question with [c#] flag or similar would give you the completly opposite answers.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like to do everything with a stoed procedure, even simple select statements. This approach have a number of benefits such as:

1. Security. The application's user does not get direct access to the tables, only to the stored procedures.
2. Encapsulation. The application doesn't need to know the table's structure - it only deals with stored procedures so it only needs to know the parameters and output of the stored procedures.
3. Easy maitenance (derived from 2). No need to recompile if something needs to be changed on the database level, as long as the stored procedure's parameters and output remains the same.

Comment: Also for testing purposes, for examle tsqlt can be used to auto-test the SPs at checkin.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the foreign key contstraint you would get an error when trying to insert a value for name_code that does not exist in First_Table:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Key". The conflict occurred in database "YourDatabaseName", table
>   "dbo.First_Table", column 'name_code'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

No row would be inserted into Second_table in this case.

Comment: I know that, in other words, there is no need to use a stored procedure?

Comment: I just forgot to mention that the primary key in the second table is "default" so It will continue to increase. I believe If I fail to insert (like in the example you gave), It will increase alone even though I didn't insert, right? so I need a sp to check and not insert?

Comment: I guess you mean that it is an identity-column? Then yes, the value will increase if an insert fails. This is normally not an issue for an identity column because they have no real meaning. When it should be a squential number, then identity is not the way you should go.